# Spring MVC and WebSockets

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, spring-4

I try to add a WebSocket end point to my Spring 4 web app.

I follow this [tutorial](http://syntx.io/using-websockets-in-java-using-spring-4/).

I created and Handler and an Interceptor and I registered them adding this configuration in the file mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml that is loaded by the 
`DispatcherServlet` .

```
<bean id="websocket" class="co.syntx.example.websocket.handler.WebsocketEndPoint"/>

<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/websocket" handler="websocket"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    <bean class="co.syntx.example.websocket.HandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>
```

My poblem is that the handler is not registered and I get a 404 error when I try to connect to

```
ws:localhost:8080/<app-context>/websocket
```

I also try to user the 'xml-less' configuration (below), but I tried to add a breakpoint in the `registerWebSocketHandlers` but the method is never invoked.

```
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/myHandler");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new MyHandler();
    }

}
```